# Ruby classes and access

Tags: ruby, class

The code below shows a `Covers` class and an `Insurers` class.

```
class Covers
  def initialize(request)
    @request = request
  end

  def top
    @request[:covers].sort_by{|k,v| -v}.first(3)
  end
end

class Insurers
  def initialize(rates, covers)
    @rates = rates
    @covers = covers
  end

  def quote
    @rates[:insurance_rates].each do |insurer_name, part|
     components =  part.split
      if components - @covers.top == []
       price =  components.select { |value| @covers.top[value]}
       price / 10
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I realised that I needed information from `Covers` in `Insurers`. I was informed that I just need to put `covers` as an initialiser in `Insurers`.

Is this correct, and is there a name for this? I felt that I could call initialiser arguments whatever I wanted, but I guess it has to be the same name as the other class in this case.

Comment: Broadly speaking this is called "dependency injection". You don't have to name the variable the same as the class, it's just a variable name so it can be anything.

Comment: I think I'm missing something in how this works. How does the Insurance class know about the content of the Covers class if the variable name isn't the same as the class name? And also does dependency injection allow me to do something like this " Insurers.new(rates, Covers.new(request)) "@maxpleaner

Comment: @b.herring: variable name is inconsequential. What matters is the actual object behind it. Like `Covers.new(request)`, yes. Perfectly good covers object.

Comment: "How does the Insurance class know " - it doesn't. You give it an object and it tries to work with it (according to code you write). If code and actual object disagree (wrong type of object, a method is missing, etc.), you'll get errors at runtime.

Comment: ok I think I understand. So the actual 'dependency injection' is the part when adding 'Covers.new(request)' into the 'Insurers.new' as an argument? @SergioTulentsev

Comment: @b.herring: yep